# Print tibble with column breaks as in v1.3.0

Tags: r, tidyverse

Using the latest version of `tibble` the output of wide tibbles is not properly displayed when setting `width = Inf`.

Based on my tests with previous versions wide tibbles were printed nicely until versions later than 1.3.0. This is what I would like the output to be printed like:

[image: tibble_ok]

...but this is what it looks like using the latest version of tibble:

[image: tibble_broken]

I tinkered around with the old sources but to no avail. I would like to incorporate this in a package so the solution should pass R CMD check. When I just copied a load of functions from `tibble` v1.3.0 I managed to restore the old behavior but could not pass the check.

There's an open [issue on Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/268) related to this problem but it's apparently 'not high priority'. Is there a way to print tibbles properly with the new version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out this function:

```
print_width_inf <- function(df, n = 6) {
  df %>%
    head(n = n) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    tibble:::shrink_mat(width = Inf, rows = NA, n = n, star = FALSE) %>%
    `[[`("table") %>%
    print()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a step forward - I get the output I expected. However, we need an unexported function from tibble which leads to a note in the check. Can we avoid that?

Comment: I know. I would like to avoid it anyway. I'm also worried that it's going to break again in a future version of tibble. If there's no way and if no one comes up with a different solution I'll happily accept the answer anyway.

Comment: What is the note?

Comment: The R CMD check complains with a "note" (not an "error" or "warning") if you use an unexported function, so if you use :::

Comment: Have you package `tibble` in your Imports or maybe Depends?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I can't use `@importFrom tibble shrink_mat`, if that was the idea, because the function is not exported. Other options?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have change, now one can just use:

```
options(tibble.width = Inf)
```